# set Currency dynamically using ironpython script in Tibco Spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I want to change currency format dynamically, I think am close to solution, but not getting proper direction, so some help is very appreciable.
below is my code.

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import BarChart
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataType
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Formatters import *

viz=barchart.As[BarChart]()
nf = DataType.Real.CreateLocalizedFormatter()
nf.Category = NumberFormatCategory.Currency
nf.DecimalDigits = 0;
viz.YAxis.Scale.Formatting.RealFormatter = nf;
```

this code so far working, but when I try to add 
`nf.CurrencyCulture='en-US`
it throw below error

```
TypeError: expected CultureInfo, got str
```

I am trying to figure out what is `CultureInfo` type is, but I am not getting anything. may be I missed something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this-

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import BarChart
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataType
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Formatters import *
from System.Globalization import CultureInfo

viz=barchart.As[BarChart]()
nf = DataType.Real.CreateLocalizedFormatter()
nf.Category = NumberFormatCategory.Currency
nf.DecimalDigits = 0;
nf.CultureInfo =CultureInfo("es-ES")
viz.YAxis.Scale.Formatting.RealFormatter = nf
```